# private and protected variable in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, what’s the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Is there a difference between a variable with a private status and a variable with a protected status?

private int toto;
protected int tata;

Comment: please do your homework before posting a question here...

Comment: it's pretty easy to google that, really.[ask]

Comment: afcorse there is a diff. thats why we have two diff names private and protected. See in details here . http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

A `private` attribute is only visible to the owning Class.
A `protected` attribute is also visible for all extending Classes, this is not the case for `private` attributes.